# How to estimate uncertainty (% error) of prediction from existing linear regression model on new inputs (out of sample data)?

Tags: regression, python, error

Say I have an independent variable (x) and a dependent variable (y) for which I modeled the relationship using a simple linear regression (ols). I then use this model to predict on new x-inputs (out of sample data). How would I get the percent uncertainty (error) for each prediction on new x inputs?

Example python code:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

## Generate test data
x = np.array([ 11.56014355, 107.27786033,  22.71480777,  29.01184381,
         0.79849564,  98.21190682,  51.07570173,   1.50033622,
        26.59511826,   0.3202299 ,  47.2756623 , 112.2986999 ,
        58.79240058])
y = np.array([ 25.86765, 268.65924,  48.85899,  86.50794,   3.43958, 230.97228,
       147.39168,   5.25603,  73.42733,   3.10752, 129.9112 , 268.29192,
       119.41919])

## Get linear regression results
model = sm.OLS(y, x).fit()

## Now, I need to use this regression to predict on new input data.
# How to get % uncertainty for each new prediction from data below?
new_x = np.array([40.1, 63.8, 87.4])
```

OLS Results:
     **coef  std err** 
x     2.44   0.059

Plotted results with CI intervals and Prediction Intervals:
[image]

```
# Get confidence intervals
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import summary_table
st, data, ss2 = summary_table(model, alpha=0.05)
predict_mean_ci_low, predict_mean_ci_upp = data[:, 4:6].T
predict_ci_low, predict_ci_upp = data[:, 6:8].T
# Get uncertainty at each original x input value
ci_uncertainty = (predict_ci_upp - model.predict())/model.predict()
# stack array to sort for easier viewing
stacked_arr = np.hstack([x.reshape(-1,1), (ci_uncertainty .reshape(-1,1)])
stacked_arr = stacked_arr[np.argsort(stacked_arr[:,0])]
print(stacked_arr)
>> array([[  0.3202299 ,   6.03804922],
>>       [  0.79849564,   4.9036087 ],
>>       [  1.50033622,   3.84203732],
>>       [ 11.56014355,   0.92422332],
>>       [ 22.71480777,   0.49614957],
>>       [ 26.59511826,   0.42677108],
>>       [ 29.01184381,   0.3925426 ],
>>       [ 47.2756623 ,   0.24515712],
>>       [ 51.07570173,   0.22775129],
>>       [ 58.79240058,   0.1995459 ],
>>       [ 98.21190682,   0.12844563],
>>       [107.27786033,   0.1203685 ],
>>       [112.2986999 ,   0.11658535]])
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "percent uncertainty". You could calculate prediction intervals, this may be what you want. You could even express their width as a percentage of the point prediction.

Comment: That approach works, however, it seems like uncertainty is very large for some. I added some figures to explain. My ultimate goal is to do a regression on an image (per pixel basis) and get uncertainty within each pixel. Each pixel has an input value on the xrange above. The model was previously trained using the data above. Here is a good example of the % error output I am looking for: daac.ornl.gov/GEDI/guides/GEDI_L4B_Gridded_Biomass.html